# Error with validation with while loop

Tags: java

im having some trouble with my validation. Here is my code

```
    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();
    while(x < -50 || x > 50 && y < -50 || y > 50)
    {
        System.out.println("Error " + a + " is out of range");
        System.out.println("Error " + b + " is out of range");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Input two integers in the range [-50, + 50]: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        b = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while( x < -50 || x > 50)
    {
        System.out.println("Error " + a + " is out of range");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Input two integers in the range [-50, + 50]: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        b = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while( y < -50 || y > 50)
    {
        System.out.println("Error " + b + " is out of range");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Input two integers in the range [-50, + 50]: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        b = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

My problem, is that the user input needs to be a & b from [-50, 50]

**But when i input -100 and 100 I only get a is out of range or b is out of range not both.**

```
Input: a= -100 b = 100
Output: 
System.out.println("Error " + -100 + " is out of range"); // CORRECT
System.out.println("Error " + 23 + " is out of range"); // ? INCORRECT
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: Your conditions are against `x` and `y` instead of `a` and `b`?

Comment: You are using `a` and `b` to get input and then you check values of `x` and `y`, is that intended and I don't understand something? And please, use parentheses in conditions, it's really hard to read and you have to wonder how it's gonna be evaluated.

Comment: You read a, b ( int a = keyboard.nextInt();) but you compare x and y

Comment: @reos Fixed. still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being naughty with your operator precedence.

`x <= -50 || x >= 50 && y <= -50 || y > 50`

is evaluated as

`x <= -50 || (x >= 50 && y <= -50) || y > 50`

You need to put in some parentheses:

`(x <= -50 || x >= 50) && (y <= -50 || y > 50)`

Also, check the precise relationship between `a`, `b`, `x`, and `y`. Why do you assign to `a` and `b`, yet then immediately test `x` and `y`?

Comment: Inattention mistake. I changed x and y to a and b.

Comment: I thought it was a typo introduced on your constructing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute values, remember **`|a| < x  means  -x < a < x`**
so both **a** and **b** must meet the criteria, or another way, you will ask as long as `**a > 50**` or `**b > 50**`

```
int a = -100;
int b = -100;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (Math.abs(a) > 50 || Math.abs(b) > 50) {
    System.out.println("need a:");
    a = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("need b:");
    b = scan.nextInt();
}
scan.close();
System.out.println("am gone!");
```

Answer (score 0):

check the while loop.
`while( x <= -50 || x >= 50 && y <= -50 || y > 50)`

both conditions need to be true to execute succesfully.check the    `&&`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, you are testing x and y but reading a and b.

Additionally, your code can be simplified:

```
boolean valid = true;
do {

    System.out.print("Input two integers in the range [-50, + 50]: ");
    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();

    if ( (a < -50) || (a > 50) ) {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("Error " + a + " is out of range");
    }

    if ( (b < -50) || (b > 50) ) {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("Error " + b + " is out of range");
    }

} while (!valid);
```

Comment: Inattention mistake, I changed x and y to a and b

Answer (score 0):

`while( x <= -50 || x >= 50 && y <= -50 || y > 50)`  Java uses "short circuit evaluation" of logical operators.  So if x = -100 and y = 0, the loop will be entered because -100 <= -50 and no other conditions matter because `true || anything` is always true.  Use parentheses to control how logical operations are processed.  I suggest putting the Boolean condition controlling the while loop into a nicely named method.

```
private boolean bothParamsAreOutOfRange(int x, int y) {
    boolean rtn = false;
    if ((x <= -50 || x >= 50) && (y <= -50 || y > 50)) {
       rtn = true;
    }
    return rtn;
}

while(bothParamsAreOutOfRange(x, y)) {
    ... as before ...
}
```